Macro Copy and Paste different workbooks
I am trying to Copy from 1 workbook (S.xls) and pasting into (PD.xlsm) based on headings. However I also get the same error 1004- Application-defined or object-defined error at this line "lastCol = sh1.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column"
Also there there a way to edit this so that it puts the number in a 11 digit format 100xxxxxxxx?
Sub Rectangle1_Click()
  Dim sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet
  Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
  Dim j As Long, lr1 As Long, lr2 As Long
  Dim f As Range
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

  Set wb1 = Workbooks("S.xls")
  Set sh1 = wb1.Sheets(1) 'origin
  Set wb2 = Workbooks("PD.xlsm")
  Set sh2 = wb2.Sheets("PD")  'destination

  'last row on origin sheet
  lr1 = sh1.Cells.Find("*", , xlValues, , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row
  'last row on destination sheet
  lr2 = sh2.Cells.Find("*", , xlValues, , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row + 1

  'for each head in sh1 (origin)
  lastCol = sh1.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
   For j = 1 To lastCol
    Set f = sh2.Rows(1).Find(sh1.Cells(1, j), , xlValues, xlWhole, , , False)
    If Not f Is Nothing Then
     sh2.Cells(lr2, f.Column).Resize(lr1).Value = sh1.Cells(2, j).Resize(lr1).Value
    End If
  Next

  wb1.Close False

  Application.ScreenUpdating = True

  MsgBox "End"`

End Sub


What about sh1.Cells(1, sh1.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column?

What does "that it puts the number" mean? In taller's comments, you revealed that it means the numbers in the 1st column but you forgot to share whether it is the 1st column of the source or destination sheet. Also, add this information to your post so a potential answer will make sense and be useful for others without having to read through the comments.

sh1 is in xls workbook wb1. It has less columns than sh2 which is in xlsx workbook wb2. That's the reason why there is a runtime error.
  'for each head in sh1 (origin)
  lastCol = sh1.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

@BigBen posted the solution in the comment.
  lastCol = sh1.Cells(1, sh1.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

Format digits with below code.
'for each head in sh1 (origin)
    lastCol = sh1.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Dim aVal, r As Long
    For j = 1 To lastCol
        Set f = sh2.Rows(1).Find(sh1.Cells(1, j), , xlValues, xlWhole, , , False)
        If Not f Is Nothing Then
            aVal = sh1.Cells(2, j).Resize(lr1).Value
            For r = LBound(aVal) To UBound(aVal)
                If VBA.IsNumeric(aVal) Then
                    aVal(r, 1) = "100" & Format(aVal(r, 1), "00000000")
                Else
                    ' for non-digits
                End If
            Next
            sh2.Cells(lr2, f.Column).Resize(lr1).Value = aVal
        End If
    Next


I only need to format the digit for the first column--Is there an easier way?

aVal(r, 1) are contents on the first col.

Copy Values From Matching Columns

The reason behind the error was revealed in your comments by BigBen and the answer by taller which boils down to the following:
Qualify Your Objects!
Each range has a worksheet, each worksheet has a workbook,... i.e.
don't use Cells, Range, Rows, Columns, Worksheets, ... without a qualifier.
Instead use ws.Cells, ws.Range, ws.Rows, ws.Columns, wb.Worksheets,... respectively.
The workbook could also be qualified i.e. Application.Workbooks(...) but it is a single possible object so you don't have to (shouldn't). Simply use Workbooks(...).
You will have to do it if you open the workbook from another application or in another instance of Excel.


An Improvement

Here's how you could improve the code.

Sub Rectangle1_Click()
    ImportDataFromS
End Sub

Sub ImportDataFromS()
    
    ' Reference the source objects (workbook, worksheet, ranges...).
    
    Dim swb As Workbook: Set swb = Workbooks("S.xls")
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = swb.Sheets(1)
    
    Dim srCount As Long: ' whole sheet
    srCount = sws.Cells.Find("*", , xlValues, , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row
    Dim scCount As Long: ' first row
    scCount = sws.Rows(1).Find("*", , xlValues, , , xlPrevious).Column
    
    ' Reference the header ('shrg') and data ('sdrg') ranges.
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = sws.Range("A1").Resize(srCount, scCount) ' all
    Dim shrg As Range: Set shrg = srg.Rows(1) ' headers
    Dim sdrg As Range: Set sdrg = srg.Resize(srCount - 1).Offset(1) ' data
        
    ' Reference the destination objects (workbook, worksheet, ranges...).
    
    Dim dwb As Workbook: Set dwb = Workbooks("PD.xlsm")
    ' If the above is the workbook containing this code,
    ' replace 'Workbooks("PD.xlsm")' with 'ThisWorkbook'.
    ' Now you can rename it as you see fit and the code will still work.
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = dwb.Sheets("PD")
    
    Dim drCount As Long: ' whole sheet
    drCount = dws.Cells.Find("*", , xlValues, , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row
    Dim dcCount As Long: ' first row
    dcCount = dws.Rows(1).Find("*", , xlValues, , , xlPrevious).Column
    
    ' Reference the header ('dhrg') and (new) data ('ddrg') ranges.
    Dim dhrg As Range: Set dhrg = dws.Rows(1).Resize(, dcCount) ' headers
    Dim ddrg As Range: ' next row resized to the number of source data rows
    Set ddrg = dws.Rows(drCount + 1).Resize(srCount - 1) ' new rows
    
    ' Return the matching source indices of the headers in a 1D one-based array.

    Dim scIndices() As Variant: scIndices = Application.Match(dhrg, shrg, 0)
    ' The array will have as many elements as there are destination columns.
    ' For each destination header, whether it was found among the source headers
    ' or not, the corresponding element in the array will hold either
    ' the source column index or an error value respectively. Therefore,
    ' the following 'scIndex' variable must be declared as a Variant.
    ' Of course, all headers of source not found in destination are irrelevant.
    
    ' Loop through the array and copy the matching columns' values.
    
    ' Declare additional variables.
    Dim scIndex As Variant, dc As Long
    
    For dc = 1 To dcCount ' btw, 'dcCount = Ubound(scIndices)'
        ' Read the source column index.
        scIndex = scIndices(dc)
        ' Write columns values.
        If IsNumeric(scIndex) Then
            ddrg.Columns(dc).Value = sdrg.Columns(scIndex).Value
        End If
        ' Apply special format only first destination column.
        If dc = 1 Then
            ddrg.Columns(dc).NumberFormat = "10000000000"
        End If
    Next dc
    
    ' Close workbook.
    'swb.Close False
    ' You usually combine this with also opening the workbook via code.
    ' But you need to specify the path to be able to open a workbook
    ' i.e. near the top of this code use e.g.
    'Dim swb As Workbook: Set swb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Test\S.xls")
    ' ... instead.
    
    ' Inform.
    
    MsgBox "Data copied.", vbInformation

End Sub

